# How can I make a external phpbb-login without redirecting to another page?

Tags: phpbb3

It's possible to make an external login with the following code

```
<form action="./phpBB3/ucp.php?mode=login" method="post">
 <h3><a href="./phpBB3/ucp.php?mode=login">Login</a>&nbsp; &bull; &nbsp; <a href="./phpBB3/ucp.php?mode=register">Register</a></h3>
 <fieldset>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="10" title="Username" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="10" title="Password" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

but this will end you up at the forum index.

If you add

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="./somefile.html" />
```

you can get it to redirect back to the page you started at, but you will still have needlessly gone to another page only to come back and have lost everything you have done on that page.

Does anyone have an idea how to make a system that lets you login without leaving the page? Maybe something with an iframe?

Answer (score 2):

This might be late but here this works:

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();

if($user->data['is_registered'])
{
    //User is already logged in
    }
else
{                    
$result = $auth->login($username, $password, '', 1, 0);

print_r($result);
if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS)
{
    echo '//User was successfully logged into phpBB';
}
else
{
    echo '//Users login failed';
}
}
?>
```

in the above code , change the `$username` and `$password` to ur login stuff , run it and see , I have tested this on the latest phpbb version, and it works.

Don't forget to change the root path and things to ur specifications.

Comment: This seems to be the same as https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?p=4012075#p4012075 . You might want to checkout the original source.